# Can I add two LEDs to this circuit?

Tags: led, circuit-design, 555

I am working on a diorama.

I found this [circuit](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/flashing-railroad-lights.html) online and it's what I want. (I'm NOT making a railroad diorama.)

I want to add two more LEDs to this circuit to have 4 flashing LEDs.  Like this:

[image: What I want]

Question: Is it that simple to parallel two more LEDs and two more resistors to create a four flashing LED system?

EDIT:
I'd like to use just a 9v battery for ease.

Comment: If you are operating at a Vcc of 12 volts then you can probably put two LEDs in series in each string.

Comment: I was going to use a 9v battery.  it's for a kid and I don't have a pwr supply

Comment: Yes, you want to use them in series with the other LED's, not in parallel as you'll burn them out. You'll also need to calculate new resistor values if you don't want them too dim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add them in series or parallel.
Series would perform best, as there is a situtation that occurs with this circuit where if the resistance is too low, the LEDs all start to glow dimly all the time.

For a 9V battery application the math to choose the appropriate resistor is as follows:

\$R=\frac{V}{I}\$

Now the voltage (\$V\$) is the battery voltage minus the forward voltage drop of each LED in the string (From Vcc to pin3, or pin3 to GND). Red LEDs can range from 1.2V to 2.4V depending on the manufacturer, power rating and such.
I'll use \$Vf=2.0V\$ and \$I=5mA\$ for this example.

\$R=\frac{9-2Vf}{0.005} = \frac{9-4}{.005} = 1000Ω\$

For your specific LEDs, you'll need to substitute the correct \$Vf\$ for the \$I\$ you plan to use, from the datasheet.

Also, when trying to do this with white LEDs, I had to use a NPN and PNP transistor to drive the top and bottom LEDs, as the resistors were too small to get the brightness I needed and the whole LED string would start to glow all the time otherwise.

This is a pretty safe and simple circuit.  Play with it and try different resistors and different LED combinations.  Doing so can lead to an intuition about how the circuit works.

Answer (score -1):

Since the ristors are only there for limiting the current going through the LED's you can simply just calculate the current by I = U/R where One LED need approx. 0.7 V (check the data sheet).

So, I would put two LEDs in series and recalculate the resistor (if necessary...).
Since each LED should be driven with 10-20 mA (again check data sheet) and need a voltage of about 0.7V it's quick math.

```
U_ges = 12 V - 2*0.7 V = 10.6 V
R = 10.6 V / 15mA
R = 706,6 Ohm
```

Check the E12 Series and you find the 680 Ohm resistor.

Comment: What kind of LEDs have a forward voltage of 0.7V? I think you are very mistaken about that.

Comment: NO  LEDs are 0.7V .Horizon , fix it or delete

Comment: The forward voltage of a red LED is about 1.8 V.  LED voltages depend primarily on the LED colour.  (0.7 V is typical for silicon diodes.)

Comment: Common red LEDs drop about 2V. 5 mA is plenty for modern LEDs, since you are using a 9V battery, you could even try less to extend battery life.